# If or while loop inside case command positional parameters

Tags: bash

Being relatively new to anything other than bash scripting, I have created a script to

- check if a process is running
- output PID's to the shell
- if not prompt user input and start etc/etc.

I've moved onto positional parameters and can't see where I'm going wrong:

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    proc_finder
elif [ $1 != "" ];then
    case $1 in
        -p | --process ) 
        shift
        z=$(ps aux |grep $1 |grep -v grep  > /dev/null)
        if [ ! -z "$z" ]; then
            echo "YES"
        else
            echo "NO"
        fi
    ;;
    * )
        echo "Usage -p (process)"
    esac
fi
```

This always seems to return `yes` even when putting in `-p test` for example.  I know im doing something fundamentally wrong, looking at the verbose output the `grep -v grep` is being done last hence I believe it always returnes an exit state of 0.

Comment: `ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep` should be simplified to `ps -C $1`, if possible - at least Linux ps is able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`?

**EDIT 1**

You can try this:

```
z=`ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep > /dev/null`
if [ ! -z "$z" ]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

If `$z` is not empty (`-z`: test for zero-length string) this implies the process was found with the `ps` command.

**EDIT 2**

The `ps ... grep ... grep` is being redirect to `/dev/null`. That means `z` will contain nothing. remove the redirection and `z` should have some output.

```
z=`ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep`
```

**EDIT 3**

Alternatively, you can just do this:

```
ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

In this case, you are not saving the grep output. That's good if you don't really need it.

Comment: Why do you have a pipe `|` after the `grep -v grep` call?
And what's the `$z` meant to be doing all by itself? That will always return 0

Comment: + case $1 in
+ shift
+ echo test
test
++ ps aux
++ grep test
++ grep -v grep
+ z=
+ '[' '!' -z == '' ']'
+ echo YES
YES

Comment: Backticks are deprecated. The $(...) construct, used by @user1217286 is much better: easy nestable, better readable.

Comment: @userunknown Thank you for pointing that out. Although I'm not sure how it would help readability, but I can appreciate the `$(...)` construct as far as nesting goes.

Comment: Backticks get sometimes overseen, and some fonts make it hard to distinguish them from apostrophes.